# How to enable lightbox effect for NextGen Gallery slideshow?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, lightbox, nextgen-gallery

I am using NextGen Gallery plugin for Wordpress. I have created a slideshow and I want to add lightbox effect there. Right now when I click on current image then slideshow moves to next image. I want to turn off this effect and instead of it when I click on current picture I want to open it in lightbox. Do you think it's possible ? I looked into source codes, but cannot find the right part of code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about using WordPress and the programming part is too generic. [wordpress.se] might be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using WordPress. you can add this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/lightbox-plus/faq/
but it has one problem- its not responsive.